# jQuery function: send a form and stay in the current page

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, function

I want to send a form and stay in the same internet page, to do that I'm using jQuery and ajax, my code is:

```
$(document).on('submit', '.commentSubmit', function() {
        var el = $(this);
        var message = el.children('textarea').val();
        if(message == '') {
            alert('you can\'t send an empty message');
            return false;
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                url: el.attr('action'),
                type: el.attr('method'),
                data: el.serialize(),
                success: function() {
                    alert('ok');
                }
            });
            return false;
        }

});
```

So it's working well but now I want to use a function so I'm doing:

```
sendMess = function(el){
        var message = el.children('textarea').val();
        if(message == '') {
            alert('you can\'t send an empty message');
            return false;
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                url: el.attr('action'),
                type: el.attr('method'),
                data: el.serialize(),
                success: function() {
                    alert('ok');
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
}


$(document).on('submit', '.commentSubmit', function() {
    sendMess($(this));
});
```

But now when I'm submiting my form I'm leaving the current page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cancel the default submit action by returning false within the handler.

```
$(document).on('submit', '.commentSubmit', function() {
    sendMess($(this));
    return false;
    // can also do "return sendMess($(this));", but less clear
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot, so I can also remove "return false" inside my function sendMess, right?

Comment: yep, no need for them, they only affect the `sendMess` function, nothing outside that

Comment: @GradislavaBikkulova this reply might be very late, but the reason why your "return false" inside sendMess is not working, is that because you forgot to also return the value *returned* by sendMess. So if you want to keep "return false" code inside sendMess, you need to add return before sendMess, like `return sendMess($(this));`

EDIT: oh, other answer has already covered this.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('submit', '.commentSubmit', function(event) {
    sendMess($(this));
    event.preventDefault()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
$(document).on('submit', '.commentSubmit', function() {
    return sendMess($(this));
    //Or return false;
});
```